# Get range/count of days based off a single date field

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have requirement where i will need to get the number of days a role an employee was on.

**Scenario 1**

```
   EmployeeId    role   effectiveFrom
      1           A      1-Jan-2021
      1           B      15-Jan-2021
```

No further roles are available for the month of Jan for role A therefore the number of days for role A would be 14.

**Scenario 2**

```
   EmployeeId    role   effectiveFrom
      1           A      1-Jan-2021
```

No further roles are available for the month of Jan therefore the number of days for role A would be 31 i.e the entire month of January. For the month of February i would expect to get 28 as the role would be effective for the entire month of february as well.

**Scenario 3**

```
   EmployeeId    role   effectiveFrom
      1           A      1-Jan-2021
      1           B      15-Jan-2021
      1           A      25-Jan-2021
```

To get the number of days for role A the logic would be

- 1 to 15th is 14 days.
- 25th to 31st(31st of Jan) would be 6 days.
- 14 + 6 = 20 days

The query i have come up with so far is this,

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(MAX(effectiveFrom),
            IF(MIN(effectiveFrom) = MAX(effectiveFrom),
                MIN(effectiveFrom),
                MIN(effectiveFrom))) + 1 daysWorked
FROM
    EmployeeRoles
WHERE grade = 'A'  
GROUP BY `employeeId`,effectiveFrom;
```

which would only give the result as 1 day for Scenario 1. Could someone guide me on the practical way of handling the scenarios. I have looked at loops, window functions but i am at a loss on the best way to proceed.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1_lAb27a)

Comment: you need to compare two rows but SELECT statement can access only 1 at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When scenario2 has 31 days from 1-jan, until the end of the month, I would suspect that from 25-jan, until the end of the month, is 7 days, and not 6, as you write in scenario3.

The number of days, using above calculation:

```sql
SELECT
   employeeID,
   grade,
   effectiveFrom,
   DATEDIFF(COALESCE(LEAD(effectiveFrom) 
                             OVER (PARTITION BY employeeID, grade ORDER By effectiveFrom),
                     DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(effectiveFrom),INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
            effectiveFrom) as '#Days'
FROM EmployeeRole;
```

This can be grouped, and summed giving:

```sql
SELECT
   employeeID,
   grade,
   SUM(`#Days`)
FROM (

SELECT
   employeeID,
   grade,
   effectiveFrom,
   DATEDIFF(COALESCE(LEAD(effectiveFrom) 
                            OVER (PARTITION BY employeeID, grade ORDER By effectiveFrom),
                     DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(effectiveFrom),INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
            effectiveFrom) as '#Days'
FROM EmployeeRole
) x
GROUP BY
  employeeID,
   grade;
```

output:

| employeeID | grade | SUM(`#Days`) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 14 |
| 1 | B | 17 |
| 2 | A | 31 |
| 3 | A | 21 |
| 3 | B | 10 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/G3vAp9vw)

EDIT: The results were incorrect because the next effectiveFrom date was determined using `OVER (PARTITION BY employeeID ORDER By effectiveFrom)`. this is not correct, because the `grade` should be taken into account too.

I corrected it to `OVER (PARTITION BY employeeID, grade ORDER By effectiveFrom)`

P.S. I also corrected this in the piece above the EDIT!

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/lEXQtwHx)

Comment: This is brilliant,Thank you! I am having a go on the second part of scenario two where i should get 28 days for February, so assuming the grade shows no change from Jan 31 onwards i should get the full number of days for the month, so Feb=28, Mar=31,Apr=30 so on & so forth. There won't be any data in the table for these months, the table would only have effectiveFrom dates.

Comment: i have data that the query is giving back a weird result. I have updated the fiddle, but should grade A be effective from 1-Jul-22 and grade B effectivefrom 13-Sep-22, both for one employeeId, i get 74 days for A (should be 31) and 18 for grade B which is correct. It seems to be considering the next effectiveFrom of the next grade as the end of the effective period whereas the months end should be considered.

Comment: @Bisoux: You said: "I have updated the fiddle", Dit you note that after each run the URL changes?  So, I did not see your update, but I think your comment was clear enough.

Comment: For data that looks like  (4,'2022-07-01','A'), (4,'2022-07-02','B') where grade A is effective from 1-Jul to 1-Jul as a different grade is effective from the 2nd of July. In this case grade A is effective for 1 day (query gives 31) and gives 30 days for grade B which is correct.

Comment: O, now I realize why I did `PARTITION BY employeeID ...`, because that will get the correct next day (from another grade).   I need to revert that change, and take the least of the next effectiveFrom, and the endOfthe Month. see:  https://dbfiddle.uk/xGfC8rZ9   (sorry, no time to do an EDIT on the answer)